How can I correct the encoding of the interactive output in my Expect/Tcl script?
I'm writing an expect script which processes input and output of Bash. Unfortunately, the output contains unwanted characters (\xc2 and \x0d). How can I avoid them with Expect/Tcl?
$ expect -f <(echo '
spawn -noecho bash -c "echo -e \"\\x80\"";
interact
') | hexdump -C
00000000  c2 80 0d 0a

Expected output: 00000000  80 0a
I tried several alternatives:
# setting LANG=C before running the script, is not an option in my use-case
$ LANG=C expect -f <(echo '
spawn -noecho bash -c "echo -e \"\\x80\"";
interact
') | hexdump -C
00000000  80 0d 0a

$ expect -f <(echo '
fconfigure stdout -encoding "iso8859-1";
spawn -noecho bash -c "echo -e \"\\x80\"";
interact
') | hexdump -C
00000000  c2 80 0d 0a

$ expect -f <(echo '
fconfigure stdout -translation "lf";
spawn -noecho bash -c "echo -e \"\\x80\"";
interact
') | hexdump -C
00000000  c2 80 0d 0a

Documentation:

https://www.tcl.tk/man/expect5.31/expect.1.html
https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.2.3/TclCmd/fconfigure.htm


Why are you using <(echo ...) instead of here-docs?

0d 0a is CR LF. Make sure your script doesn't have DOS-style newlines, and fix it with dos2unix.

The Tcl runtime usually auto-translates CRLF sequences in scripts; dos2unix likely won't help. Configuring the channel(s) used by Expect might though I've never done that.

c2 80 sounds like the other program is using UTF-8.

expect adds carriage returns for newlines, to remove carriages:
LC_ALL=C expect <<'EOF' | perl -pe 's/\r\n/\n/' | hexdump -C
spawn -noecho bash -c "echo -e '\\x80'"
interact
EOF

